# Join new data to selected features in a table using Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have a point feature class, A, and I have joined data from another point feature class, B, to its attribute table based on spatial location. I selected the second option in the Join Data window (*'Each point will be given all the attributes of the point in the layer being joined that is closest to it ...'*). It worked perfectly and all fields from B (say Field_1 and Field_2) are added to A.

Then I added two new records to A (two new points to shapefile) and I want to join data from a different point feature class, C, to these two new points. C has exactly the same fields as B but their values are different. I want data from C to be added to the same fields (Field_1 and Field_2) that are already imported from B, but for these new points. I am wondering Is there any way that I can join data from C to selected features in A (these two new points) in ArcGIS?

P.S. I am using ArcGIS 10.1 on Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the two records to A, make a new feature class with them called D. Join the fields in C to your new feature class D. Then use the Merge tool to combine A and D.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a more straightforward solution but it seems that your solution is the best option. Accepted ;)  @stanleykubrick